# When should I start farming Crawmerax minions for efficient leveling?

Tags: borderlands

I'm a level 47 Siren right now and I'm killing some of the minions that Crawmerax spawns to try to quickly boost my level. They're level 61 - 62 and while I do get some good experience from killing them, it is a really really slow process and I feel like I'm wasting my time.

At what point should I start trying to kill the minions of Crawmerax to quickly boost my level?

Comment: Just some advice for your level, [Drifters](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Drifter) give some serious XP and can be killed very quickly using rockets while in the Monster. You're far enough into the General Knoxx DLC that finding them should not be an issue. I used them to farm up to level 58 in no time.

Comment: That's on playthrough 2 right?

Comment: In playthrough 2 exclusively. The General Knoxx DLC alone should get you to 61 with only a little experience farming on Drifters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best point to start doing that is when you can kill the spawns with only a few hits (less than 20 or so usually).  In order to achieve this, you have to know their elemental weaknesses.

The green ones are weak to fire.  The fast blue worms are weak to electric, and the armored ones are weak to acid.

To get some good elemental weapons, try farming the last mission of the Armory DLC, there is a [glitch](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=slGfVhqF7Wg) you can do to get unlimited armory time, as far as I know its still possible to do it.  If you don't want to exploit the glitch, then you can do the missions that give you a second and third crack at getting something decent in the armory.  (or you can go online and try to find a crawmerax farm to get a good weapon).  Keep in mind anything crawmerax drops will be very high level anyway.

Comment: Right now I'm getting about 50-60 hits to kill one Craw Maggot, so I'll probably come back when I hit the mid 50s

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, I think the Eridian Promontory is the best place to get XP. The Eridian aliens give up a tremendous amount of XP, and if you have some good static weapons (or if you are a hunter with trespass maxed out) they are relatively easy. At the very least, I'd say that for gaining XP, they are certainly more effective than dealing with Crawmerax and his minions.

UPDATE: The "non-DLC" content will NOT be under-leveled provided you complete the mission "Find Steele" (on playthrough 2), and your level is at least 49. This is because ALL enemies will scale with you, and hands down the Eridian Promontory is the easiest place to farm once this happens. They will be about 2 levels above you and they give far more experience than equal level creatures of a different type. Please follow the link for more [information on enemy level scaling](http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?t=111858).

Comment: I thought about doing that as well since this method of XP grinding isn't working very well for me so far. I'll have to try there next... Thx!

Comment: The aliens are far under-leveled for the second playthrough of the General Knoxx DLC ... so their XP value drops off fast. There are far better ways to farm XP, I'd avoid all non-DLC areas like the plague.

Comment: LittleTreeX's suggestion is good though, if his level is still below 50, the aliens are quite good xp, especially if you use shock weapons as they have high shields low health

Comment: I have added a bit more info in my answer. Technically, the aliens can be good XP all the way to level 69. See above for more info.

Comment: the only draw back of the aliens when compared to crawmerax is that crawmerax spawns his minions constantly, well that and crawmerax drops sweet loot

Comment: @LittleTreeX Is that only in playthrough 2.5? Or was 2.5 removed from the game and now things just scale? For an old player like me a history lesson might help :)

Comment: @Sadly Not - I only know my own experience. I played Borderlands when it first came out for a few months, and then took a very long break until this summer. When I came back it seemed to work as above. I do not think the game just scales outright, as I am pretty sure you have to complete playthrough 2 for the scaling to take effect. If you read the link it also indicates that General Knoxx has a hard fixed starting level of 50. And you must beat the main story in it, before it too starts scaling.