# Where can I find defeated quest enemies?

Tags: borderlands

Following on from my [previous question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29953/what-high-level-enemies-respawn-in-borderlands), it seems that all defeated quest enemies such as Skyscraper, the Rakk Hive, Skagzilla, etc will respawn at or near their original locations.

Since the Borderlands game world is really big and I can only ever remember a few of these big baddies, I was hoping we could compile a list of enemies and their spawn locations (and a rough XP gain from killing them, if possible) for faster farming.

A few enemies I remember off the top of my head to start off the list are below. Even if I come across some of them sometimes, I don't remember the name of the spawn areas!

- Skyscraper
- Skagzilla
- Motorhead
- Mothrakk
- Rakk Hive
- Crawmerax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of what you are looking for can be found on the [borderlands wiki](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Borderlands_Wiki)

However, to answer the questions about your specific bosses:

- [Skyscraper](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Skyscraper) - It spawns under the separate broken highway against the
  far edge of the map, at nearly a straight connecting line from the
  World's Largest Bullet and Thirsty the Midget.
- [Skagzilla](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Skagzilla) - He's part of the mission Big Game Hunter in Dahl Headlands, and he respawns inside the pen area.
- [Motorhead](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Motorhead) - Motorhead respawns every 15 minutes at the quest location.
- [Mothraak](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Mothrakk) - Mothraak respawns when you approach the torches.
- Rakk Hive - The Rakk hive is a special type of boss respawn which only happens after you've beaten playthrough 2.  His location remains unchanged from the quest location.
- [Crawmerax](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Crawmerax_the_Invincible) - He's always in the usual spot, he respawns when you leave/reenter the area.

Most of these bosses respawn when you restart your game unless otherwise stated.

As for XP gain, it entirely depends on your level.  Farming bosses typically is not worth doing for xp, but rather for drops.  [This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30252/when-should-i-start-farming-crawmerax-minions-for-efficient-leveling/30255#30255) is also pertinent if you want to get lots of xp.